# How to improve performance score of lighthouse for a complex angular page?

Tags: angular, lighthouse

The lighthouse score for our angular pages wasn't very good and with lighthouse v6 the performance score has gone down dramatically. I've looked for ways to improve things and I can say I am following the standard, but what I noticed is that all these examples and guides are based on simple pages on angular. But what about those more advanced, more complex?. What do you guys recommend for situations like this? How can I improve things so that the Largest Contentful Paint is below 4s as to meet google's requirements for good ranking? Here are some of these pages:

https://wallethub.com/profile/credit-one-bank-13001903i

https://wallethub.com/personal-loans

https://wallethub.com/savings-accounts/chase-13001251i

https://wallethub.com/checking-accounts

Comment: what are some of your ideas for what is causing the performance problems? are you executing large amounts of javascript? doing animations? sounds?

Comment: My only suspicion is the javascript bundle and the fact that it's too big. Since the one main one is like that. For example, for profiles its 300 kb gzipped. But all that is there is used, all is needed for initiation of all the sections. The bundles are done with rollup.js and I tried to squeeze out as much as I could. I am now trying to create a splitting configuration in hopes that smaller chunks are faster than one big one. 
Do you think that's the cause? is too much stuff being rendered at? But I don't see how can things be left out when all sections are needed...

Comment: Maybe using Angular Universal for SSR helps

Comment: We are using angular universal. In fact, we do special server-side only rendering for bots. But it doesn't seem to help. Seems this is becoming a real problem based on this thread: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13446